# If $y'+y=|x|$ and $y(-1)=0$, what is $y(1)$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, problem-solving, boundary-value-problem

> If $y'+y=|x|$ and $y(-1)=0$, what is $y(1)$?

I calculated the integrating factor to be $e^x$.

Then $e^x y'+ e^x y=e^x |x|$ hence $\frac {d(e^x y)}{dx}=e^x |x|$ hence $d(e^x y)=e^x|x|dx $

Integrating both sides,

$e^xy=e^x \int |x|dx- \int [(\int |x|dx)(e^x)]dx +c.$

From here how to proceed?

Can I write $\int |x|dx=-2 \int xdx, x \lt 0$? Then I will get the constant $c$ by using $y(-1)=0$. But how will it help me to calculate $y(1)$?

Comment: No, "integrating both sides" (and using your somewhat faulty notations),
one gets $e^xy=\int e^x |x|dx$, hence $$ey(1)=e^{-1}y(-1)+\int_{-1}^1e^x|x|dx=\ldots$$

Comment: Can I know my faulty notations?

Comment: Usually, the notation $\int g(x)dx$, leaving the bounds of the integral unspecified, already includes an additive constant.

Comment: @Did Okay thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \lt 0$, then

$$y' + y=-x$$

The general solution is

$$y(x) = C e^{-x} +1-x$$

$$y(-1) = C e + 2 = 0 \implies C = -2/e$$

and for $x \gt 0$

$$y'+y = x$$

so that $y(x)$ in this region is

$$y(x) = D e^{-x}-1+x$$

We find $D$ by requiring continuity at $x=0$:

$$1-\frac{2}{e} = D-1 \implies D = 2 -\frac{2}{e}$$

Thus,

$$y(1) = \left ( 2 -\frac{2}{e} \right ) e^{-1} = \frac{2}{e} - \frac{2}{e^2} $$

Comment: You worked on $x \lt 0$. Then how did you used the information gathered from it on $x \gt 0$? i.e. at $x=1$? Actually answer is $\frac 2e -\frac 2{e^2}$ and suggestion of @Did really works.

Comment: @VikrantDesai: Thanks for pointing out the error.  Fixed.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Error fixed.  I should not attempt these first thing in the morning!

Comment: @RonGordon hahaha. :D Thanks a lot. I like this solution too! :)

Comment: @Ron Coffee before mathematics. Always. :-)

Comment: @Did: I hate coffee.  I'm not sure what Erdős would have done with me.

Comment: @Ron True. Note that the Great Man used other substances as well, but one cannot recommend these publicly I am afraid.